# Get first day of a specific month

Tags: android, date, time, calendar

I know, there are plenty of similar questions, but my question is a bit more specific and complicated:

I want to get the first day of month (and of the following month), from a specific month.

My current code:

```
private long getFirstTime(Time inputTime) {
        Time t = new Time();
        t.set(inputTime);
        t.monthDay = 1;
        t.normalize(true);

        return t.toMillis(true);
}

private long getLastTime(Time inputTime) {
        Time t = new Time();
        t.set(inputTime);
        t.monthDay = 1;
        t.month++;
        t.normalize(true);

        return t.toMillis(true);
}
```

The inputTime is always the time of a month in the future or past.

Generated like this:

```
Time mTimeMinus = new Time();
            mTimeMinus.set(System.currentTimeMillis());
            mTimeMinus.month--;
            mTimeMinus.normalize(true);

Time mTimePlus = new Time();
            mTimePlus.set(System.currentTimeMillis());
            mTimePlus.month++;
            mTimePlus.normalize(true);
```

Any ideas for a fix?

---

Code in the question is working as intended, the problem was a different one!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use this something like this

```
public String getFirstDay(int day, int month, int year)
    {
        Calendar cal = new GregorianCalendar();
        cal.set(Calendar.DATE, day);
        cal.set(Calendar.MONTH, month);
        cal.set(Calendar.YEAR, year);
        cal.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, 1);
        switch (cal.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK)) {
            case Calendar.SUNDAY:
                return "SUNDAY";
            case Calendar.MONDAY:
                return "MONDAY";
            case Calendar.TUESDAY:
                return "TUESDAY";
            case Calendar.WEDNESDAY:
                return "WEDNESDAY";
            case Calendar.THURSDAY:
                return "THURSDAY";
            case Calendar.FRIDAY:
                return "FRIDAY";
            case Calendar.SATURDAY:
                return "SATURDAY";
        }
        return null;
    }
```

Comment: Solved, the code in the question was working as intended, the error was in another location ...